# discord.py add role on message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Ive seen a lot of questions about this and none of them worked for me, I don't understand why something that sounds this simple is that complicated, alredy spent more than 4 hours on this, I want to make a basic bot to make new users accept the rules:

Not much to explain, just a basic bot that when you say accept in a special channel it should add you a role.

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    #creates a message for users to react to
    guild = client.guilds
    channel = client.get_channel(836583535981608530)
    Text= "Type accept below if you understand and `accept` ALL the rules in <#836600011484785843>, in order to gain access to the server:"
    await channel.send(Text)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    channel = message.channel
    if channel.id == 836593532981608530 and message.content.lower() == ('accept'):
        await message.delete()
        user_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = "role name")
        new_member = message.author
        new_member.add_role(user_role, reason = "new member")
    elif channel.id == 836593532981608530:
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: You need to await the statement. You would have an error that a statement wasn't awaited. My answer will explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here in your command is that you have not `awaited` statement(s) that had to be `awaited` for library to work.

So, let's start.

#### The statement(s) that needs to be awaited:

```
new_member.add_role(user_role, reason = "new member")
```

#### How to fix this error?

You need to `await` it just like you have awaited other statements in your code.

Just change the line to:

```
await new_member.add_roles(user_role, reason="new member")
```

This would solve the problem you have facing.

#### Why do you need to `await` some statements?

Read the docs from the following link to see why some statements are needed to be `awaited`. This would help you to figure out what commands has to be `awaited` in future.

---

Hope it helps. If still you have any problem, feel free to ask me in the comments. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: Still doesn't work, says: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'add_role'

Comment: Oh oops. That is `add_roles` not `add_role`. I am really sorry! I didn't notice that.

Comment: Changed it now please check it.

Comment: That worked!!! I was soo close. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You're welcome! If I was of help, please accept this answer. :)